# Searching for a font name

Tags: fonts

which kind of font has been used in this picture?[image]

I want to sart my sentences with this font ,

Comment: `\LaTeX{}` is the way.

Comment: Are you asking for the font used for those letters or asking how to produce the latex logo?

Comment: I am asking for the font

Comment: why show it as a logo then:-) Do you have that document in electronic form? If so you can just extract the answer from the pdf

Comment: No, I do not have it, that is why I put its picture

Comment: @David :it does not work for me

Comment: @user3559542 the question is then not really a TeX question (and is off topic) as it isn't about how to use the font in tex but rather if anyone recognises that letter shape, as such it would be better in a graphic design or typography forum than here. Although you might be lucky and someone spot it.

Comment: where (what book or publication) did you get this logo.  it is not the "standard" (computer modern) form of the logo since the spacing is too generous.

Comment: lucida? perhaps

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my experience, the output of `\LaTeX` often looks wrong with other fonts. I assume Knuth crafted the specifics of `\LaTeX` to fit with his CM font?

Comment: @Sverre -- indeed knuth did craft the specifics of `\TeX` to fit with the cm fonts (`\LaTeX` is someone else's invention), but it's not really difficult (just tedious) to adapt it to a different font.  knuth, in [a tugboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb07-2/tb15knutlogo.pdf), addressed this question with respect to the various cm fonts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This inspired me to write a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249437/redfine-latex-command) about that.