# Redefine \LaTeX command

Tags: macros

From [How can I see the "implementation" of the \LaTeX command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17886/how-can-i-see-the-implementation-of-the-latex-command) and [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-parentheses-or-any-other-tex-related-logo), I learn that `\LaTeX` is implemented as

```
L\kern -.36em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.15em\TeX
```

The `\kern` parameter needs to be tweaked according to the font used, as pointed out by Knuth in a [TUGboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb07-2/tb15knutlogo.pdf). When trying to change that parameter in the code above, however, I get the error `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \z`.

How can I tweak the `\kern` value of the `\LaTeX` command (and of the `\TeX` command)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern -.20em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.10em\TeX}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\LaTeX` is a protected definition

Comment: @SeanAllred True, but I think that's independent of the problem I raise above (I get the same error if I use `\newcommand{\mylatex}{...}`).

Comment: Look at the `hologo` and `metalogo` packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command being used is `\z@`, not `\z`.  Wrap the redefinition in `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern -.20em{\sbox \z@ T\vbox to\ht \z@ {\hbox {\check@mathfonts \fontsize \sf@size \z@ \math@fontsfalse \selectfont A}\vss }}\kern -.10em\TeX}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\LaTeX
\end{document}
```

Comment: These values work pretty well for sourcesanspro font from Adobe.